# Testing hypothesis that mean of grouped quantitative data is increasing in one direction

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, trend, boxplot

My predictor variable is quantitative, but falls into nine discrete groups (i.e., values are either 60, 125, 200 etc.). I have a responder variable that is quantitative and continuous. I have made a boxplot, and want to test the hypothesis that the average for each box & Whisker (responder variable) increases along the x-axis (predictor variable). An Anova test isn't appropriate as it only tells me whether the means are different, not whether they are changing progressively in one direction. A regression doesn't seem appropriate as the x axis isn't continuous. Any suggestions?

Comment: For a linear regression, the x axis does not have to be continuous. Just think about dummy variables, they aren't continuous either.

Comment: Something like [Spearman's rank correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient)?